# How can I dump a database directly to an s3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I want to initiate a database backup from an ec2 instance and save that backup directly to my s3 bucket without saving to the database on either instance. Something like this:

`ssh -l admin 172.0.0.23 "mysqldump -uuser -pxxx database_name | gzip -3 -c" > 'arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket'`

The example does not quite work because the database is saved to the initiating instance to a file called 'arn:aws:s2:::my_bucket'.

Comment: This worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52113216/1641112 Closing as a duplicate.

Comment: Where is the database running? Is it on an EC2 instance, or Amazon RDS, or something else? What is your main driver in not wanting to save an interim file (eg security, speed, storage space, reliability)?